# add video on blog post

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, blog, video

I want to embed video on blog posts. For that I want to have share video/ insert video option to be available on ribbon while adding new blog post.By googling I found few links as

[Embedding Video in Blog Post?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/51253/embedding-video-in-blog-post)

&
http://blog.vgrem.com/2013/09/26/embedding-video-to-a-sharepoint-library/

Any simpler approach/idea other than this how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint 2013 MS has Introduced a new Video Content Type that supports adding Videos on SharePoint Pages,Content Webparts and even Content Field Types like Post body

1. Firstly, Get the Video Code – You can either use the Code for a [Video from YouTube](http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2012/09/03/how-to-add-a-youtube-video-in-sharepoint-2013/) or you can use the Embed Code of a Video that you [Uploaded in SharePoint (in Asserts Library)](http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2012/08/05/how-to-add-a-video-to-sharepoint-2013-site/).If you are adding a Youtube Video you need to add the “Youtube.com” Domain in “HTML Field Security” first.[See the Post How to add a Youtube video in Sharepoint 2013 for reference](http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2012/09/03/how-to-add-a-youtube-video-in-sharepoint-2013/).
2. Once you have the code you can paste it into the Post body.Open the blog post where you want to to add the Video and in the Insert tab select “Embed”

[image]

3. Paste the Code in the Embed window and click ok.

[image]

You can also use other options like From Computer, From SharePoint and From Address to upload Videos.

Source: http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2012/12/16/how-to-add-video-in-blog-post-in-sharepoint-2013/

Also check this one:
http://community.bamboosolutions.com/blogs/sharepoint-2013/archive/2013/07/25/how-to-insert-videos-to-a-blog-post-in-sharepoint-2013.aspx

Comment: nope....!! I am on SharePoint 2010...!! :(